# Dynamically create functions in React to be consumed for react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've been trying sort out how to create functions dynamically while trying to teach myself react-router-dom following the first example here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start

I've sorted out how to create the Router & Switch stuff, but I'm at loss on how to create the supporting functions at the end of the example.

What I tried was this:

```
makeFunctions() {
    const { charList } = this.state;
    charList.map(char =>
        char.name.split(" ")[0] = function instance(){
            return <h2>{char.name.split(" ")[0]}</h2>;
        }    
    )
}
```

I'm using the Star Wars API (swapi.dev).

Take it for given that char.name.split(" ")[0], is stuff like "Luke", "Leia", Obi-wan".

What I need to produce is:

```
function Luke() {
    return <h2>Luke</h2>;
  }
function Leia() {
    return <h2>Leia</h2>;
  }
function Obi-wan() {
    return <h2>Obi-wan</h2>;
  }
```

..to complete the example I'm following.   Am I close?  Am I off by miles? Is this possible or simple just the wrong way to go about this?  Any direction is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

To answer the questions popping up below.  I really don't understand React or Router all that well and am kinda winging it here.  The specific example I'm following from the link above is this:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

I've dynamically rendered everything inside of App(){} from my charList fetched from swapi.dev, but I'm a loss at how to make the supporting functions at the end work as they (in the example) follow the naming of the router link & switch route statements.

Comment: When you say functions do you really mean you want a Route for each character? I guess we should start with what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, to perhaps understand the path you've started going down. Generally speaking though, functions will need to be defined ahead of time (remember, this is technically a webpage, so the code is fetched).

Comment: So you want to dynamically create functions? I guess the [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) constructor is the way to do that - but why would you want to? Why make loads of separate functions when it appears you can use a single one with the name as an argument?

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese!  I updated the question so it's clearer I hope.

Comment: Thanks @RobinZigmond!  I'm green as green when it comes to React.  I'm all ears if this the dumb way to do it ;-)  Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: @fbonds66 I guess you could maybe use `<Route path='/:charName'>` and have a single component for all characters, and inside that component you can check router params to get the name ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm still not quite understanding the desire to create one-off functions and I think Hassan and I are in agreement that it sounds more like you want to be able to dynamically handle displaying different character data depending on name. A Route with the character name as part of the path is a common pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it I think

```
window[char.name.split(" ")[0]] = function () { // your code }
```

and then you can simply call them by

```
window['Luke']();
```

although I'd suggest having a single function and pass the char name as param i.e.

```
let charNameHeader = function (name) {
  return `<h2>${name}</h2>`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand your need exactly, but if you want to create some functions dynamically you can group them inside an object

```js
//let's say you have this array
const starWarsCharacters = ["Lia", "Luke", "Whatever"];

//we can now declare an empty object
const starWarsFunctions = {}

//and then we create functions this way 
starWarsCharacters.map(el => starWarsFunctions[el] = function(){ return el})

// we can then call the function this way
console.log(starWarsFunctions.Lia())
console.log(starWarsFunctions.Luke())
```